# MVC 5 e EF 6 Colocar Formulario de uma outra view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Continua dando o erro de comentário *null* nesta linha:

```
ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Titulo", comentario.PostId);
```

Provavelmente por que não entou no `ModelState.IsValid`.

Estou fazendo um projeto lá da faculdade. Meu projeto é um Blog, algo simples. O que estou precisando agora é na View de cada Artigo colocar um Formulário embaixo para a pessoa postar os comentários daquele Artigo. Como faço? Por que o submit seria pra o `ComentarioController` só que ele esta na *view* do artigo.

Formulario que esta na View Post:

```razor
@model WebBlog.Models.Post
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Post";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="post-title">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Titulo)</div>
    <div class="postmeta">Postado em 13/05/2014 | por @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Autor.Nome)</div>
    <div class="entry">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Conteudo)</div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="post-title">Comentarios</div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Comentarios)
    {
        <div class="postmeta">
            <div class="comment-author">
                <span class="fn">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Autor)</span>
                <div class="commenta-meta">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.dataComentario)</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="entry">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.comenatrio)</div>
    }
</div>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="post-title">Envie seu Comentario</div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comentario", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostId)

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="dataComentario">Data Comentario:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" name="dataComentario" class="disabled" disabled="disabled" id="dataComentario" value="@System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Autor">Autor:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" name="Autor" id="Autor" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Comentario">Comentario:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <textarea class="control-label col-md-2" id="Comentario" name="Comentario"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Comentar" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Agora o Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(
    [Bind(Include="ComentarioId,PostId,dataComentario,Autor,comenatrio")] 
    Comentario comentario)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Comentarios.Add(comentario);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Post", "Home", new {PostId = comentario.PostId});
    }

    ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Titulo", comentario.PostId);
    return View(comentario);
}
```

O erro que ocorre é que ele não entra nesse `if (ModelStatte.IsValid) { ... }`.
Daí quando vai pra linha da `ViewBag` dá o erro. Observei que o Model `Comentario` não esta sendo instanciado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sobre o apontamento do form para um *Controller* e uma *Action* específica:

Você pode especificar para onde o submit será apontado!

```html
<form actiom="~/Comentario/Adicionar" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Ou:

```cs
@Html.BeginForm("Adicionar", "Comentário", FormMethod.Post)
{
    ...
}
```

Ou até mesmo:

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="formComentario">
   ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#formComentario").submit(function () {
            $(this).attr("action", "/Comentario/Adicionar");
        });
    });
</script>
```

## Sobre o erro em seu *Controller*:

Sobre o erro no Controller, vamos a alguns detalhes

- Você disse que o *Model* `Comentario` não está sendo instânciado.

Se realmente não estiver sendo instânciado o valor que você deve ver nele ao debugar é o *`null`*.
Se realmente for isso, teste colocar em sua *View* a tipagem, caso não tenha:

```cs
// algo como
@model Models.Comentario
```

- Se não for *`null`*, mas sim uma classe instânciada e com os valores *default* de vazio: 0 para *`int`*, vazio para *`string`*:

Então pode ser algo no qual estou acreditando. Que é o seguinte:
Sua view está declarada manualmente e estou vendo nos campos os ***Id´s*** e ***name´s*** como `dataComentario` e `comentario`. Porém creio que não deva ter deixado os campos de sua classe no padrão *lowerCamelCase*. Acredito que esteja como:

```cs
public DateTime DataComentario { get; set; }
public string Comentario { get; set; }
```

Então, verifique esses itens e retorne o que conseguir encontrar.
Sobre não estar entrando no escopo do `if (ModelStatte.IsValid) { ... }` é exatamente por seu Model não ter sido instânciado ou não ter todos os campos de acotdo com o que é necessário para validá-lo. Conforme definido em suas anotações da classe, ou pelo seu mapeamento *Fluent*.

O padrão do *Framework MVC* do *ASP.NET* é que os campos tenham exatamente o mesmo nome que a propriedade da classe para ele efetuar o parser para você.

A idéia de usar os ***Helpers*** é para que o ***Razor*** trate isso para você, como:

```cs
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Comentario)
```

Será gerado:

```html
<input type="text" id="Comentario" name="Comentario" />
```

Comment: Veja o trecho de código do Create: if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Comentarios.Add(comentario);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Post", "Home", new {PostId = comentario.PostId});
            }

            ViewBag.PostId = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostId", "Titulo", comentario.PostId);
            return View(comentario); Poré esta retornando o erro na ViewBag:  Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Vou editar a Pergunta colocando o trecho de codigo do meu Formulario e do meu controller.

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado.